# Trying to append a click function to the node text in d3

Tags: d3.js, modal-dialog

I'm trying to generate a modal with information pulled from my json file when the text of a node is clicked on. I'm having trouble, so I'm just trying to generate an alert box at the moment. I think that I need to declare a variable for the node text, but I'm having trouble. Here is what I have right now:

```
  node.append("svg:text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dy", "3.5em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })

  var textNodes = node.append("svg:text").text()
  .on("click", function(d, i) { alert("Hello world"); });
```

Or this, I don't see why this wouldn't work either.

```
node.append("svg:text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dy", "3.5em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .on("click", function(d) { alert("Hello world"); });
```

Comment: At a glance, I don't see anything wrong with the second example; could you post a fiddle or bl.ocks?

Comment: Here's a link to bl.ocks. The pictures are local, but I'm not worried about that. [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/caseymm/6001040)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are explicitly setting `pointer-events: none` for the text nodes (maybe a copy and paste error). Removing this line in the styles allows the click event to fire.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do do recogize a click on the label using something like this:

```
    const text = this.g.selectAll('text')
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append('text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .style('fill-opacity', function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
    .style('display', function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 'inline' : 'none'; })
    .style('pointer-events', 'auto')
    .on("click", function(d) {
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
      console.log(d.data.name);
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.name});
```

Answer (score 0):

to expand on the topic, the following function

```
d3.event.stopPropagation();
```

will make the node not expand or collapse if you clicked on the text but the node will continue to expand and collapse if you clicked on the node circle next to the name. Pretty neat.